# Laravel Mutator Database Value with Variable variables

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Laravel Eloquent Mutator

```
public function getUsedWorkingTimeAttribute($db = null)
{
   return is_null($db) ? $this->getUsedDaysOfKind('working time', true, 120) : $db;
}
```

When calling `$object->used_working_time` i get the value stored in the database as expected.

When using Variable variables `$object->{'used_'.$name}` with `$name = 'working_time'` the `$db` value is null.

Is there a way to get the database attribute with the second way. I am using Laravel 8.74 and PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a variable first and then use it with object as bellow:
and make sure there is no space in string else replace it with underscore

```
$variable = 'used_' . $name;
$object->$variable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately the $db value is still null so it does not change anything.

Comment: Maybe as I remember, you can try like that $variable = 'used_' . $$name;

because when you are using with one $ sign it returns just string, and with $$ two signs it would be actually as variable.

Comment: no, that also does not work...

Comment: I checked again and my problem was using `$object->attribute` in the `$name` variable.